# Check variable is an array in Bourne like shell?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ksh, yash

In Bourne like shell which support array variable, we can use some parsing to check if variable is an array.

All commands below were run after running `a=(1 2 3)`.

`zsh`:

```
$ declare -p a
typeset -a a
a=( 1 2 3 )
```

`bash`:

```
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")'
```

`ksh93`:

```
$ typeset -p a
typeset -a a=(1 2 3)
```

`pdksh` and its derivative:

```
$ typeset -p a
set -A a
typeset a[0]=1
typeset a[1]=2
typeset a[2]=3
```

`yash`:

```
$ typeset -p a
a=('1' '2' '3')
typeset a
```

An example in `bash`:

```
if declare -p var 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'declare -a'; then
  echo array variable
fi
```

This approach is too much work and need to spawn a subshell. Using other shell builtin like `=~` in `[[ ... ]]` do not need a subshell, but is still too complicated.

Is there easier way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Under what circumstances would you need to check whether your variables are arrays or not?

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can, and I don't think it actually makes any difference.

```
unset a
a=x
echo "${a[0]-not array}"
```

---

```
x
```

That does the same thing in either of `ksh93` and `bash`. It looks like possibly *all* variables are arrays in those shells, or at least any regular variable which has not been assigned special attributes, but I didn't check much of that.

The `bash` manual talks about different behaviors for an array versus a string variable when using `+=` assignments, but it afterwards hedges and states that the the array only behaves differently in a *compound* assignment context.

It also states that a variable is considered an array if any subscript has been assigned a value - and explicitly includes the possibility of a null-string. Above you can see that a regular assignment definitely results in a subscript being assigned - and so I guess everything is an array.

Practically, possibly you can use:

```
[ 1 = "${a[0]+${#a[@]}}" ] && echo not array
```

...to clearly pinpoint set variables that have only been assigned a single subscript of value 0.

Comment: So I guess checking if `${a[1]-not array}` can do the task, can't it?

Comment: @cuonglm - Well, not according to the `bash` manual: *An array variable is considered set if a subscript has been assigned a value.  The null string is a valid value.* If any subscript is assigned its an array per spec. In practice, also no, because you can do `a[5]=x`. I guess `[  1 -eq "${#a[@]}" ] && [ -n "${a[0]+1}" ]` could work.

Answer (score 6):

So you effectively want just the middle part of `declare -p` without the junk around it?

You could write a macro such as:

```
readonly VARTYPE='{ read __; 
       case "`declare -p "$__"`" in
            "declare -a"*) echo array;; 
            "declare -A"*) echo hash;; 
            "declare -- "*) echo scalar;; 
       esac; 
         } <<<'
```

so that you can do:

```
a=scalar
b=( array ) 
declare -A c; c[hashKey]=hashValue;
######################################
eval "$VARTYPE" a #scalar
eval "$VARTYPE" b #array
eval "$VARTYPE" c #hash
```

(A mere function won't do if you'll want to use this on function-local variables).

---

## With aliases

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias vartype='eval "$VARTYPE"'

vartype a #scalar
vartype b #array
vartype c #hash
```

Comment: @mikeserv Good point. Aliases make it look prettier. +1

Comment: i meant - `alias vartype="$VARTYPE"`... or just  not defining the `$VARTYPE` at all - it should work, right? you only should need that `shopt` thing in `bash` because it breaks with the spec regarding `alias` expansion in scripts.

Comment: @mikeserv I'm sure cuonglm is well capable of tweaking this approach to his needs and preferences. ;-)

Comment: ... and security considerations.

Comment: At no point does the above code eval user provided text. It's no less secure than a function. I've never seen you fussing about making functions read-only, but OK, I can mark the variable readonly.

Comment: well, true, and it didn't matter when you just used `eval`, because you only targeted the one definition, but when you `alias x='eval "$x"'` it may not be immediately apparent to some that the `alias` and `$x` are connected *over time*. you know what I mean? i mean that a lot of people may think the `alias` definition sticks even if the variable doesn't - that's all i'm getting at... but you can't portably make functions `readonly`, and i've only now learned you can at all...

Answer (score 6):

In zsh

```
zsh% a=(1 2 3) s=1
zsh% [[ ${(t)a} == *array* ]] && echo array
array
zsh% [[ ${(t)s} == *array* ]] && echo array
zsh%
```

Comment: Maybe `echo ${(t)var}` is simpler. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 4):

To test variable var, with

```
b=("${!var[@]}")
c="${#b[@]}"
```

It is possible to test if there are more than one array index:

```
[[ $c > 1 ]] && echo "Var is an array"
```

If the first index value is not zero:

```
[[ ${b[0]} -eq 0 ]] && echo "Var is an array"      ## should be 1 for zsh.
```

The only hard confusion is when there is only one index value and that value is zero (or one).

For that condition, it is possible to use a side effect of trying to remove an array element from a variable that is not an array:

```
**bash** reports an error with             unset var[0]
bash: unset: var: not an array variable

**zsh** also reports an error with         $ var[1]=()
attempt to assign array value to non-array
```

This works correctly for bash:

```
# Test if the value at index 0 could be unset.
# If it fails, the variable is not an array.
( unset "var[0]" 2>/dev/null; ) && echo "var is an array."
```

For zsh the index may need to be 1 (unless a compatible mode is active).

The sub-shell is needed to avoid the side effect of erasing index 0 of var.

I have found no way to make it work in ksh.

#### Edit 1

This function only works in bash4.2+

```
getVarType(){
    varname=$1;
    case "$(typeset -p "$varname")" in
        "declare -a"*|"typeset -a"*)    echo array; ;;
        "declare -A"*|"typeset -A"*)    echo hash; ;;
        "declare -- "*|"typeset "$varname*| $varname=*) echo scalar; ;;
    esac;
}

var=( foo bar );  getVarType var
```

#### Edit 2

This also work only for bash4.2+

```
{ typeset -p var | grep -qP '(declare|typeset) -a'; } && echo "var is an array"
```

Note: This will give false positives if var contains the tested strings.

Comment: How about array with zero elements?

Comment: Dat edit, tho. Looks very original. :D

Comment: @cuonglm The check `( unset "var[0]" 2>/dev/null; ) && echo "var is an array."` correctly reports var is an array when var has been set to `var=()` an array with zero elements. It acts exactly equal to declare.

Comment: The test for scalar won't work if the scalar is exported or marked integer/lowercase/readonly... You can probably safely make it that any other non-empty output means scalar variable. I'd use `grep -E` instead of `grep -P` to avoid the dependency on GNU grep.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The test (in bash) for scalar with integer and/or lowercase and /or readonly always start with `-a`, like this: `declare -airl var='()'`. Therefore the grep test will **work**.

Comment: I meant that `getVarType HOME` would not report `scalar` for instance. Nitpick: `getVarType -a`, `getVarType varname`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I believe that getVarType will not work in most corner cases. The limited pattern matching being the reason. I plan on changing to regex (some form of it) to resolve the issue. I'll ping you when done.

Comment: If you do it `...array/hash;; ("") ;; (*) scalar`, I think it should work. A variable should be either scalar, array or hash in `bash` (even namerefs can be considered as scalar I'd say).

Answer (score 4):

For **bash**, it's a little bit of a hack (albeit documented): attempt to use `typeset` to remove the "array" attribute:

```
$ typeset +a BASH_VERSINFO
bash: typeset: BASH_VERSINFO: cannot destroy array variables in this way
echo $?
1
```

(You cannot do this in `zsh`, it allows you to convert an array to a scalar, in `bash` it's explicitly forbidden.)

So:

```
 typeset +A myvariable 2>/dev/null || echo is assoc-array
 typeset +a myvariable 2>/dev/null || echo is array
```

Or in a function, noting the caveats at the end:

```
function typeof() {
    local _myvar="$1"
    if ! typeset -p $_myvar 2>/dev/null ; then
        echo no-such
    elif ! typeset -g +A  $_myvar 2>/dev/null ; then
        echo is-assoc-array
    elif ! typeset -g +a  $_myvar 2>/dev/null; then
        echo is-array
    else
        echo scalar
    fi
}
```

Note the use of `typeset -g` (bash-4.2 or later), this is required within a function so that `typeset` (syn. `declare`) doesn't work like `local` and clobber the value you are trying to inspect. This also does not handle function "variable" types, you can add another branch test using `typeset -f` if needed.

---

Another (nearly complete) option is to use this:

```
    ${!name[*]}
          If name is an array variable, expands to  the  list
          of  array indices (keys) assigned in name.  If name
          is not an array, expands to 0 if name  is  set  and
          null  otherwise.   When @ is used and the expansion
          appears within double quotes, each key expands to a
          separate word.
```

There's one slight problem though, an array with a single subscript of 0 matches two of the above conditions. This is something that mikeserv also references, bash really doesn't have a hard distinction, and some of this (if you check the Changelog) can be blamed on ksh and compatibilty with how `${name[*]}` or `${name[@]}` behave on a non-array.

So a *partial* solution is:

```
if [[ ${!BASH_VERSINFO[*]} == '' ]]; then
    echo no-such
elif [[ ${!BASH_VERSINFO[*]} == '0' ]]; then 
    echo not-array
elif [[ ${!BASH_VERSINFO[*]} != '0' ]]; 
    echo is-array    
fi
```

I have used in the past a variation on this:

```
while read _line; do
   if [[ $_line =~ ^"declare -a" ]]; then 
     ...
   fi 
done < <( declare -p )
```

this too needs a subshell though.

One more possibly useful technique is `compgen`:

```
compgen -A arrayvar
```

This will list all indexed arrays, however associative arrays are not handled specially (up to bash-4.4) and appear as regular variables (`compgen -A variable`)

Comment: The `typeset +a` also reports an error in ksh. Not in zsh, though.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

For the two shells that introduced this notation (`bash` and `ksh93`) a scalar variable is just *an array with a single element*.

Neither needs a special declaration to *create* an array. Just the assignment is enough, and a plain assignment `var=value` is identical to `var[0]=value`.

Comment: Try: `bash -c 'unset var; var=foo; typeset -p var'`. Do bash answer report an array (needs an -a)?. Now compare with: `bash -c 'unset var; var[12]=foo; typeset -p var'`. Why is there a difference?. A: The shell maintains (for good or for bad) a notion of which vars are scalars or arrays. The shell ksh do mix both concepts into one.

Answer (score 1):

[yash's `array` builtin](http://yash.osdn.jp/doc/_array.html) has some options that only work with array variables. Example: the `-d` option will report an error on non-array variable:

```
$ a=123
$ array -d a
array: no such array $a
```

So we can do something like this:

```
is_array() (
  array -d -- "$1"
) >/dev/null 2>&1

a=(1 2 3)
if is_array a; then
  echo array
fi

b=123
if ! is_array b; then
  echo not array
fi
```

---

This approach won't work if array variable is *readonly*. Trying to modify a *readonly* variable leading to an error:

```
$ a=()
$ readonly a
$ array -d a
array: $a is read-only
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

var=BASH_SOURCE

[[ "$(declare -pa)" =~ [^[:alpha:]]$var= ]]

case "$?" in 
  0)
      echo "$var is an array variable"
      ;;
  1)
      echo "$var is not an array variable"
      ;;
  *)
      echo "Unknown exit code"
      ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of bash (4.4+), you can just use the attribute operator on the variable expansion.

e.g.

```
bob=()
declare -A rob
rob[mob]=bob

echo ${bob@a}
>>> a
echo ${rob@a}
>>> A
```

Note simply declaring the associative array will not print its attribute -- you must assign something to it first.