# Can I introspect the type of a bash variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, variable, array, arguments

I'm writing a function that outputs dates. I'd like to allow the user to customize the output by supplying arguments to `date` with an environment variable. To preserve white space in format strings, I'd like to accept args in an array like this:

```
function argdates {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ] && date "${DATE_ARGS[@]}" -d @$1
    do shift
    done
}
```

The user might want to use an array if they have spaces in a date format string:

```
DATE_ARGS=( -u "+%y/%U, %I%p %a" )
argdates 1476395008 1493172224

# output:
# 16/41, 09PM Thu
# 17/17, 02AM Wed
```

But in this case, an array might be overkill:

```
DATE_ARGS="-u -Iseconds"
argdates 1476395008 1493172224

# output:
# date: invalid option -- ' '
# Try 'date --help' for more information.

# output should be:
# 2016-10-13T21:43:28+00:00
# 2017-04-26T02:03:44+00:00
```

I don't want to require an array for simple cases like this. Is it possible to tell what type the variable is?

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/246026/38906

Comment: In the second case, what's so hard about writing `DATE_ARGS=(-u -Iseconds)`?

Comment: You can't export an array as an environment variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script

Comment: @Barmar yes that's basically where I'm at right now: Assume end user is comfortable creating a bash array. But the common way to export arguments for a script to use is the second example, not with an array.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you may want to let your function pass on any command line options directly to GNU `date` while treating numerical non-option specially:

```
argdates () {
    local -a opts
    local timestamp

    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" != '--' ] && [[ "$1" != [0-9]* ]]; do
        opts+=( "$1" )
        shift
    done
    [ "$1" = '--' ] && shift

    for timestamp do
        date "${opts[@]}" -d "@$timestamp"
    done

    # or, with a single invocation of "date":
    # printf '@%s\n' "$@" | date "${opts[@]}" -f -
}
```

This `bash` function would go through its command line arguments and save them in the `opts` array, until it hits an argument which is `--` (the standard way of signalling the end of options) or that starts with a digit. Each argument saved into `opts` is shifted off of the list of command line arguments.

Once an argument has been found that is not an option to `date`, we assume that the rest of the arguments are UNIX epoch timestamps and loop over these, calling `date` with our saved options for each timestamp.  See the comment in the code for how to do this looping more efficiently.

Example invocations:

```
$ argdates 1476395008 1493172224
Thu Oct 13 23:43:28 CEST 2016
Wed Apr 26 04:03:44 CEST 2017
```

```
$ argdates -- 1476395008 1493172224
Thu Oct 13 23:43:28 CEST 2016
Wed Apr 26 04:03:44 CEST 2017
```

```
$ argdates +%D 1476395008 1493172224
10/13/16
04/26/17
```

```
$ argdates +%F 1476395008 1493172224
2016-10-13
2017-04-26
```

```
$ argdates -u 1476395008 1493172224
Thu Oct 13 21:43:28 UTC 2016
Wed Apr 26 02:03:44 UTC 2017
```

```
$ argdates -u -Iseconds 1476395008 1493172224
2016-10-13T21:43:28+00:00
2017-04-26T02:03:44+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that much easier by giving up on using arrays and letting the user specify `DATE_ARGS` simply as a string that should be inserted in the command line of `date`:

```
$ argdates(){
    for d; do printf %s "$DATE_ARGS" | xargs date -d "@$d"; done
}
$ DATE_ARGS='-u "+%y/%U, %I%p %a"' argdates 1476395008 1493172224
16/41, 09PM Thu
17/17, 02AM Wed
$ DATE_ARGS='-u -Iseconds' argdates 1476395008 1493172224
2016-10-13T21:43:28+00:00
2017-04-26T02:03:44+00:00
```